# Expo error: Image upload not working in expo android

Tags: react-native, expo

Image upload not working in expo android

```
async function uploadImages() {
        const token = ""
 
        const workforceId = "ea3be847-c237-4191-aebc-9490d0f78fab";
        //const selectedImage = selectedImage
        console.log(selectedImage)
        const fileType = 1;
 
        const headers = {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
 
        try {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('WorkforceId', workforceId);
            formData.append('file', selectedImage);
            formData.append('fileType', fileType);
 
            console.log(formData)
 
            const response = await axios.post('https:/ff2f-160-202-36-170.ngrok-free.app/workforce/fileupload', formData, {
                headers: headers
            });
 
            console.log(response.data); // true or false
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw error;
        }
    }
```

I am using the above function to upload image files in react native expo app but it is giving a network error. Anyone please check what's wrong in above function?

above function should upload images

Comment: Add detail error message from `catch`

Comment: @indresh can you post the whole error?

Comment: {"_parts": [["WorkforceId", "c7e0e538-ae88-48c4-8772-c00a85e2e137"], ["file", "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540indresh149%252FKushalKaamgar/ImagePicker/7f80649d-9950-4531-80f3-1c9d045ac515.jpeg"], ["fileType", 1]]}
 LOG  [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400]
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 2):
[AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400]

this is the complete error i am getting, I am getting bad request 400